# Does this kind of matrix operator exist and if so what is it called?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question

I am an engineer working in some data problem and suddenly I come across this presentation issue that I do not even know how to frame it correctly.

Particularly, my original data matrix $A$ consist entirely of zeros and ones as follows :

$A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&1\\
1&1&0&1\\
0&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0
\end{array}} \right]$

Now I need to construct a matrix $B$ from matrix $A$ that will have this form :

$B = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{1T}&{2T}&0&0\\
{1T}&{2T}&0&{4T}\\
{1T}&{2T}&0&{4T}\\
0&{2T}&{3T}&{4T}\\
0&0&{3T}&{4T}\\
0&0&{3T}&0
\end{array}} \right]$

The interesting property of matrix $B$ is that all of the ones from matrix $A$ are now replaced by the column index times some amount of time period $T$ that is related to the engineering problem.

I have been looking for some kind of operator $V$ that when I perform on $A$ would give me the result of $B$ but I seem to have been stuck. I have gut feelings that a smart manipulation of the Kronecker product might help but I cannot come up with any idea on how to proceed.

Does this kind of matrix operator exist and if so what is it called ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: It is just a right-multiplication of $A$ by a diagonal matrix. In your example, $B=A\operatorname{diag}(T,2T,3T,4T)$.

Comment: Nice , @user1551 , though we can simplify it to use "Constant" Diagonal Matrix with Scalar Multiplication by variable $T$ : $B=TAD$ : where $B$ is what we want , $A$ is what we have , $T$ is variable time & $D$ is "Constant" Diagonal Matrix.

Comment: @Prem can you be more concrete, I am just an engineer so I cannot imagine about your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending & modifying what user [user1551](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1551/user1551) said earlier :

$$A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&1\\
1&1&0&1\\
0&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0
\end{array}} \right]$$

Let $D$ be constructed like this :

$$D = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&0&0&0\\
0&2&0&0\\
0&0&3&0\\
0&0&0&4\\
\end{array}} \right]$$

Now we can construct the matrix $B$ from given Matrix $A$ & Constant Matrix $D$ & Scalar Constant $T$ like this :

$$ B = TAD $$

This $B$ will match what OP wanted.

In Case this is a Programming Issue , Matrix $D$ can be "constructed" easily with C/C++ or Perl or Python or R.

Comment: Thank you , @NeckverseHerdman , for fixing my blind "Copy-Paste" actions ! With your update , OP will then know that Square Matrix $D$ must match the Number of Columns of Matrix $A$ , in general !

Comment: Thank you  so much